# Color based Kalman Filter

Tags: python-3.x, opencv, kalman-filter

As my research, Kalman Filter can include color information for prediction or object tracking. However, I cannot found any implementation in OpenCV. Can anyone give me some example?

Can I simply change the Kalman creation like: `cv2.KalmanFilter(7, 5)` 5 for position and RGB?

Comment: Kalman filter IS implemented in OpenCV. [Here is the documentation](https://docs.opencv.org/3.4/dd/d6a/classcv_1_1KalmanFilter.html) You have to define the matrices of the Kalman filter and the rest is done for you.

Comment: I have some update on the question. Is that possible the implement like this?